# Check for 3rd party software and remove it

Tags: linux, package-manager

Please recommend Linux software for checking completely removal of 3rd party software from the operating system, e.g.:

1. I creating my filesystem's capture from the software, that I seeking;
2. installing some 3rd party software;
3. removing some 3rd party software;
4. run some checking function from the software, that I seeking;
5. see the results of checking, which have paths of some undeleted files from my disk.

Comment: Please specify the [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution#Widely_used_distributions) of the target system.

Comment: @agc, the Debain Linux v. 9-10-based OS.

Comment: That helps, there are ways, but we still need more information. Please describe an example of how the 3rd party software might have been installed on Debian.

Comment: @agc, via dpkg or via proprietary software installing tool.